# UIWindow and Statusbar

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog, uiwindow

I have a `DialogViewController` that I load up for the main UI (login)

```
        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        var logonView = new LogonViewController();
        window.AddSubview(logonView.View);
```

The problem is that the status bar **hides the top 5 mm** or so of the screen.

How do I tell the `UIWindow` to be the size of the available screen, and not the screen which includes the Statusbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you set the root view controller instead?

```
    window.RootViewController = logonView;
```

If you call AddSubview instead of setting the RootViewController you should get the warning "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch", and some things (such as rotation) will not work correctly.

Otherwise you could probably set `logonView.Frame` to account for the size of the status bar.